# Jenkins Email notification - Report Summary

Tags: shell

I've a few HTML reports generated after a Multi-Configuration Jenkins Job is run, which I attach with the email notifications triggered at the end of the job. I would like to know if there's a way to parse only a part of the HTML file (the summary table at the beginning of the reports) and display them in the content body of the email (Editable email plugin).

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this plugin. This will allow you more control over the HTML script in Jenkins. Visit https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Comment: I'm using this plugin, but I want to pull out just the summary table from the test results and print on the content body of the email.